# UIScrollViewDelegate method only called when view is initialised

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, delegates, uiscrollviewdelegate

I'm trying to set a scrollView method that will essentially disable the bounce at the bottom of the view. So, I've made my view controller conform to UIScrollViewDelegate:

```
 class MainViewController: I6ViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate
```

I've set the scrollView's delegate to self in my init:

```
scrollView.delegate = self
```

And I'm trying to trigger this method;

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.height {
        scrollView.contentOffset.y = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.height
    }
}
```

However, whilst the method is called when the view is initialised. it is never called subsequently when scrolling. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try to set the delegate in viewDidLoad method? also what is scrollView here? where does it being declared?

Comment: Are you *sure* it's not being called? Put a `print(#function)` statement in there to confirm.